# Firefox extension, opening a local file in a new foreground tab from menu

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I am learning how to program Firefox extensions. I have created a new menu and when the menu item is clicked, I want a new tab to be opened, in the foreground, containing a local file contained within the contents directory.

For example:

MENU -> Item1

When Item1 is selected, I want a new tab to open in the foreground containing what is located in /myextension/content/content.html.

Where can I find out how to do this?

---

For clarity, I can get the local file to open in a new tab, I just do not know how to get to open in a new focused tab.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following function to open a tab, make sure it hasn't already been opened and switch focus to it:

```
function OpenAndReuseOneTabPerURL(url)
{

    var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
    var browserEnumerator = wm.getEnumerator("navigator:browser");

    // Check each browser instance for our URL
    var found = false;
    while (!found && browserEnumerator.hasMoreElements())
    {
        var browserWin = browserEnumerator.getNext();
        var tabbrowser = browserWin.gBrowser;

        // Check each tab of this browser instance
        var numTabs = tabbrowser.browsers.length;
        for (var index = 0; index < numTabs; index++)
        {

            var currentBrowser = tabbrowser.getBrowserAtIndex(index);
            if (url == currentBrowser.currentURI.spec)
            {

                // The URL is already opened. Select this tab.
                tabbrowser.selectedTab = tabbrowser.tabContainer.childNodes[index];

                // Focus *this* browser-window
                browserWin.focus();

                found = true;
                break;

            }

        }

    }

    // Our URL isn't open. Open it now.
    if (!found)
    {

        var recentWindow = wm.getMostRecentWindow("navigator:browser");
        if (recentWindow) {

            // Use an existing browser window
            recentWindow.delayedOpenTab(url, null, null, null, null);

        } else {

            // No browser windows are open, so open a new one.
            window.open(url);

        }

    }

}
```

Use it like:

`OpenAndReuseOneTabPerURL("http://yoururl.com");`